# Creating HTML body with javascript/DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Ok basically I want to store part of  `body` tag inside a `variable` in `function` and call the function in the body to create that part of the HTML. 
Here's my code for the function:

```
 function RadioButtonContent()
 {
var rbc = '<h3>Type your radio button here:</h3><input type="text" name="option" id="option" value="Example 1" /><button id="AddButton" onclick="radio()">Add</button><button id="RemoveButton">Remove</button><div id="updateDivRadio"><h1>Space for Radio Button</h1></div>'
var rbcAppen = document.getElementById('radioButton');
rbc.appendChild.rbcAppen;
 }
```

But it doesn't do anything when called... may be DOM doesnt work this way or is there a way around?
[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/nadz006/WYf3G/1/) the fiddle.

Please help

Comment: You may want to use the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/innerHTML) property if you're looking to do this.

Comment: Yeah I have a feeling that might be the case... any ideas how? @Seiyria

Comment: I would use a hybrid of my statement and the answer below, I'll post it in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a new node and set its HTML, like so:

```
var newNode = document.createElement("div")
newNode.innerHTML = rbc;
rbcAppen.appendChild(newNode);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsbin.com/cebikuxi/1/edit

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nadz006/WYf3G/1/) is the fiddle with your code @Seiyria... not working :(

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: RadioButtonContent is not defined ` on your fiddle. I'll see if I can get a fix going.

Comment: @envyM6 I'm also using chrome and getting that error. Hmm.

Comment: That's because the jsfiddle was wrapping `RadioButtonContent` in an onload See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/WYf3G/2/. You cannot create a text node from HTML

Comment: LOL may be my PC is drunk then... :P
But seriously im not getting error

Comment: @Seiyria you rock man!!! Thanks a lot... it works!! Post it as answer please I'll accept :)

also any idea why the same code doesnt do anything in Js fiddle? I mean I copied your code to the fiddle but its still doesnt work :/

Comment: @envyM6 For the reasons outlined above by Juan. I've updated my answer. Enjoy!

Comment: @Seiyria last question... how to add an id to the `div` that has been created by `newNode` ?

Comment: @envyM6 set `newNode.id = 'idValue'`

Comment: @Seiyria excellent... now i Have another problem that is caused by the `radio` function

Comment: @envyM6 I would recommend opening another stackoverflow topic with your specific problem and an example there to work with.

Comment: how can i tag you there?

Comment: Send me a link. Also, please don't forget to mark this question as answered if it's run its course correctly for you.

Comment: Yh marked!! Do you want me to send you link here? or is there any way to message you? I dont think stackoverflow allows messaging between users :/ @Seiyria

Comment: It does, but I don't know what the reputation requirements are for doing so. Pasting it here should be alright.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nadz006/KcLj6/2/) is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nadz006/KcLj6/2/)
The problem is `Add` button doesnt respond first time. Second time it does and then instead of creating one radio button it creates two, third time three, fourth time four and so on !

Comment: I mean, link me to the new question, we can continue our discussion there.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769234/add-button-acts-weird) you go :) @Seiyria

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode

```
// For text only
rbcAppen.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rbc))

// If you can overwrite the HTML in rbcAppen
rbcAppen.innerHTML = rbc;

// If you  can't overwrite the HTML, create a temporary node, add 
// the content there and append the nodes  to your rbcAppen
var tempNode = document.createElement("div");
tempNode.innerHTML = rbc;
while (tempNode.childNodes.length) {
    rbcAppen.appendChild(tempNode.childNodes[0]);
}
```

[Working code](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/WYf3G/4/)

Comment: thanks..
`rbcAppen.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rbc))` works but it doesnt put the content as html element and tags, instead it puts them just as plain text, which is not my intention...

Comment: @envyM6 I've updated the answer to cover other cases

Comment: Awesome @Juan Mendes... your fiddle actually works!!
Please have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nadz006/KcLj6/2/)