# Add button acts weird

Tags: javascript, html

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nadz006/KcLj6/3/) is the fiddle.

The problem is Add button doesn't respond first time. Second time it does and then instead of creating one radio button it creates two, third time three, fourth time four and so on.

```
function RadioButtonContent()
{
    var rbc = '<h3>Type your radio button here:</h3><input type="text" name="option" id="option" value="Example 1" /><button id="AddButton" onclick="radio()">Add</button><button id="RemoveButton">Remove</button><div id="updateDivRadio"><h1>Space for Radio Button</h1></div>';
    var rbcAppen = document.getElementById('radioButton');
    var newNode = document.createElement("div");
    newNode.innerHTML = rbc;
    rbcAppen.appendChild(newNode);
}

function radio()
{
    function createRadioElement(elem, label, checked) {
        var id = 'option1_' + label;
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="option1" id="' + id + '" value="1" /><label for="' + id + '">' + label + '</label>';
        document.getElementById('updateDivRadio').appendChild(div);
    }

    document.getElementById('AddButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var x = document.getElementById('option').value;
        createRadioElement(this, x);
    });


    document.getElementById('RemoveButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        [].forEach.call(document.getElementById('updateDivRadio').querySelectorAll("input"), 
            function (el) {
                if (el.checked) {
                    el.parentNode.remove();
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: I clicked show and each time it creates one. Latest FF on mac

Comment: Hi @Huangism.... Its the `Add` button that functioning weird not `Show` button. Start clicking `Add` button after you have clicked `Show`.

Comment: The problem is that you call `radio()` on every click. You need to check if there is already a listener and not add a new one if there is one.

Comment: Yes there is!!! OMG how did I miss that... Can you help me to rectify my `radio` function please? post and I'll accept.. I'll start retyping the codes as well @Seiyria

Comment: @envyM6 Tesserex has posted a great example already.

Comment: Yeah..... Got it :) You guys are awesome!! @Seiyria

Comment: @Seiyria `Remove` button is not working now :(

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcLj6/4/) by Tesserex

Comment: @envyM6 I would wait for his reply.

Comment: I'll be waiting too :( @Seiyria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML has an `onclick` attribute for the buttons, but then inside the handler, you add more handlers! You shouldn't have the `addEventListener` calls inside the `radio` function. Each time you click, it's adding another handler, so the next click makes it do it an additional time.

http://jsfiddle.net/KcLj6/5/

Updated to fix remove button.

There is an updated fiddle where I've rearranged the code a bit. You need to choose to either put the callback in `onclick`, or use `addEventListener`, not both.

Comment: Hi again @Tesserex.... the remove button is not functioning now... can you please help me to debug it too please?

Comment: @envyM6 Fixed it I think.